# Flutter raw autocomplete suggestions get hidden under soft keyboard

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a raw auto complete widget.
The issue is if the widget is at the center or around the bottom of the screen, when I start typing the auto suggestions shown gets hidden under the soft keyboard. How to build the optionsViewBuilder to overcome the hiding of the options under the keyboard?

Sample source code:

```
class AutoCompleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  const AutoCompleteWidget(
    Key key,
  ) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AutoCompleteWidgetState createState() => _AutoCompleteWidgetState();
}

class _AutoCompleteWidgetState extends State<AutoCompleteWidget> {
  late TextEditingController _textEditingController;
  String? _errorText;
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  final GlobalKey _autocompleteKey = GlobalKey();
  List<String> _autoSuggestions = ['abc', 'def', 'hij', 'aub', 'bted' 'donfr', 'xyz'];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawAutocomplete<String>(
      key: _autocompleteKey,
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      textEditingController: _textEditingController,
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return _autoSuggestions;
        }
        return _autoSuggestions.where((dynamic option) {
          return option
              .toString()
              .toLowerCase()
              .startsWith(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        });
      },
      optionsViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
          AutocompleteOnSelected<String> onSelected, Iterable<String> options) {
        return Material(
          elevation: 4.0,
          child: ListView(
            children: options
                .map((String option) => GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        onSelected(option);
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(option),
                      ),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
      fieldViewBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        TextEditingController textEditingController,
        FocusNode focusNode,
        VoidCallback onSubmitted,
      ) {
        return Card(
          elevation: (null == _errorText ? 8 : 0),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
          child: TextField(
            controller: textEditingController,
            focusNode: focusNode,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: No. I had move to using the dropdown / dropdown_search widget.

Answer (score 3):

A solution I came up with was using was building my own version of a simple  autocomplete widget using a `TextFormField` and setting `scrollPadding` on it. I'm showing the results in a container with a set height that works with that padding.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: [
        // THE AUTOCOMPLETE INPUT FIELD
        TextFormField(
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 300),
          maxLines: null,
          key: const ValueKey('company_address'),
          autocorrect: false,
          enableSuggestions: false,
          controller: widget.textEditingController,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value!.isEmpty) {
              return _i10n.enterAName;
            }
            return null;
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: widget.labelText,
          ),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          onChanged: (_) {
            _handleChange();
            widget.onChange();
          },
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _showAutocompleteSuggestions = true;
            });
          },
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5.0,
        ),
        // THE AUTOCOMPLETE RESULTS
        if (_showAutocompleteSuggestions)
          Container(
            // height: _autocompleteHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(blurRadius: 10.0, color: Colors.black12)
              ],
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200.0),
            child: Scrollbar(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(children: [
                  if (_autocompleteSuggestions.isEmpty)
                    const ListTile(
                      title: Text('No results'),
                    )
                  else
                    ..._autocompleteSuggestions.map((_autocompleteSuggestion) =>
                        Material(
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              _handleSelectSuggestion(_autocompleteSuggestion);
                            },
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
                              title: Text(_autocompleteSuggestion.description),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ))
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Forgive the quick code dump.

Answer (score 1):

**Positioning of Options View:**

The optionsViewOpenDirection property is set to               **optionsViewOpenDirection: OptionsViewOpenDirection.up,**
This ensures that the options view will open above the text field, allowing it to be visible even when the soft keyboard is displayed.
*emphasized text*

**Adjustment in Options View Builder:**

The optionsViewBuilder is wrapped within an Align widget with **alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter**. This alignment positions the options view at the bottom of the screen, aligned with the text field.

```
  RawAutocomplete<ItemData>(
          textEditingController: controller,
          optionsViewOpenDirection: OptionsViewOpenDirection.up,
          optionsViewBuilder: (context,
              Function(ItemData) onSelected, options) {
            return Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: // your code,
            );
          },
          
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some constraints to achieve the behavior you want.

First of all, place the root widget as a child of `LayoutBuilder` to get the layout constraints (I also used a Align top place the options view better).

After that, you can use a `ConstrainedBox` as the parent of your options view.

You can customize these constraints as you want. The example below is set to have half screen height as the max height of the options view minus the bottom view inset (dynamic as the state of the soft keyboard).

The code you gave on your example would be something like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) => Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 16,
      ),
      child: RawAutocomplete<String>(
        key: _autocompleteKey,
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        textEditingController: _textEditingController,
        optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
          if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
            return _autoSuggestions;
          }
          return _autoSuggestions.where((dynamic option) {
            return option
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .startsWith(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
          });
        },
        optionsViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
            AutocompleteOnSelected<String> onSelected,
            Iterable<String> options) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxWidth: constraints.biggest.width,
                  maxHeight: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2) -
                      (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom / 4),
                ),
                child: ListView(
                  children: options
                      .map((String option) => GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              onSelected(option);
                            },
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(option),
                            ),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        fieldViewBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          TextEditingController textEditingController,
          FocusNode focusNode,
          VoidCallback onSubmitted,
        ) {
          return Card(
            elevation: (null == _errorText ? 8 : 0),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
            child: TextField(
              controller: textEditingController,
              focusNode: focusNode,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use SingleChildScrollView on your screen where RawAutocomplete places with reverse: true property.

Just like beneath:

```
child: Center(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    reverse: true,
    child: Column()
```