# Flutter AutoComplete Suggestion appearing below the soft keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete

I am using the official Autocomplete widget, but when I'm typing for suggestions, the suggestions are appearing above the soft keyboard. I want the suggestions to always be visible above the keyboard.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5LqT.png)

My code:

```
 LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (_, BoxConstraints constraint){
                  return Autocomplete<String>(
                    optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue){
                      if(textEditingValue.text.isEmpty){
                        return const Iterable.empty();
                      }
                      return _countryList.where((element) => element.contains(textEditingValue.text));
                    },
                    onSelected: (selectedValue){

                    },
                    fieldViewBuilder: (context, controller, focusNode, onEditingComplete){
                      return TextFormField(
                        controller: controller,
                        focusNode: focusNode,
                        onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
                        decoration:   InputDecoration(
                            border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary)
                            ),
                            hintText: "Search your country"
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      );
                    },
                    optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options){
                      return Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Material(
                          elevation: 5,
                          child: ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                              maxWidth: constraint.maxWidth,
                            ),
                            child: ListView.separated(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                                  return InkWell(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16,vertical: 8),
                                      child: Text(options.elementAt(index)),
                                    ),
                                    onTap: (){
                                      onSelected(options.elementAt(index));
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                separatorBuilder: (context,index)=> Divider(
                                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                                ),
                                itemCount: options.length,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
```

I want the suggestions to always be visible above the keyboard.

Comment: Not possible. How would the user type if something is covering the keyboard?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66737473/flutter-2-0-autocomplete-widget-goes-out-of-screen-from-right-side
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70199780/flutter-raw-autocomplete-suggestions-get-hidden-under-soft-keyboard
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68287781/flutter-widget-hides-behind-keyboard-when-it-opens