# How can i avoid the issue of options in Autocomplete widget in flutter hidden by keyboard popup

Tags: flutter, autocomplete

I created a Autocomplete widget to show option when typing in the field , but some part of options list is hidden by the keyboard popup. I want to see the full options list

```
 Autocomplete<String>( 
       fieldViewBuilder: (context, textEditingController, focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) {
         return TextField(
          controller: textEditingController,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          onSubmitted: (value) {
          
       
          },
           style:const TextStyle(
             color: Colors.white, // Change this color to the desired text color
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
       
          label: const Text("Search your school"),
          labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              textStyle:
                  const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Color(0xFF495792))),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: const Color(0xFF1B223F),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF232C52))),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF232C52))),
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 52),
        ),
         );
       },
        optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue schoolValue) { 
            
          // if user is input nothing 
          if (schoolValue.text == '') { 
            return const Iterable<String>.empty(); 
          } 
            
          // if user is input something the build  
          // suggestion based on the user input 
          return schoolOptions.where((String option) { 
            return option 
                .contains(schoolValue.text.toLowerCase()); 
          }); 
        }, 
       
          
        // when user click on the suggested 
        // item this function calls  
        onSelected: (String value) { 
       
          debugPrint('You just selected $value'); 
        }, 
               ),
```

i tried giving it a scrollview and dismissing keyboard on scrolling, but not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70199780/flutter-raw-autocomplete-suggestions-get-hidden-under-soft-keyboard
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66737473/flutter-2-0-autocomplete-widget-goes-out-of-screen-from-right-side
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68287781/flutter-widget-hides-behind-keyboard-when-it-opens